# Удивительные библиотеки Python

Tags: python, numpy

Хотел поизучать устройство numpy внутри, а именно класс np.array(я думал, что это класс). Но оказалось, что это функция) Вот её сигнатура:

```
def array(p_object, dtype=None, copy=True, order='K', subok=False, ndmin=0):
```

Далее в теле функции длинный, длинный docstring, а потом `pass`... И возникает вопрос, а где же собственно сам код? Как создаётся объект класса np.ndarray в следующем коде:

```
import numpy as np


print(np.array)
```

Туда ли я попал? Или это файл а-ля заголовочный в C++? (Хотя не уверен, что такие есть в Python...)

P.S. Открыл документацию функции с помощью горячих клавиш ctrl + ЛКМ в pyCharm.

Comment: https://github.com/numpy/numpy

Comment: Насколько я знаю, ключевая часть numpy написана на c++. А в питон-коде, видимо, просто заглушки оставили для этой логики.

Comment: Но ведь должен же быть хотя бы return...

Answer (score 2):

То что у вас открылось - это stub файл с сигнатурами функций, автоматически восстановленный из скомпилированной библиотеки. В моем случае открывается так:

Файл _multiarray_umath.py

```
# encoding: utf-8
# module numpy.core._multiarray_umath
# from /home/user/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
# by generator 1.147
# no doc
# no imports

...

def array(p_object, dtype=None, copy=True, order='K', subok=False, ndmin=0): # real signature unknown; restored from __doc__
    """
    ...
```

Обратите внимание на комментарий `# real signature unknown; restored from __doc__` в строке с сигнатурой функции. Также в моем случае файл восстановлен из файла `_multiarray_umath.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` (под windows скорее всего будет файл с расширением dll вместо so), о чем написано в самом начале данного модуля.

Реальные исходники библиотеки нужно смотреть на гитхабе: https://github.com/numpy/numpy